# Pass global function to stylus files

Tags: node.js, stylus

I'm trying to define a function that will be available inside all my .styl files. So for example, I could write:

```
body
    background-image STATIC('/dist/assets/myImage.jpg')
```

which should output

```
body {
  background-image: url('//localhost:3000/dist/assets/myImage.jpg')
}
```

Inside my gulp task

```
gulp.task('stylus', function() {
  // host is defined in our config settings
  // i.e. for develpoment it will be "localhost:3000"
  var host = require('../../config').host;

  return gulp.src('src/main.styl')
    .pipe(stylus({
      define: {
        STATIC: function(file) {
          return 'url("//' + host + file.val + '")';
        }
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/dist/css'));
});
```

However, when I run `gulp stylus`, the entire output is quoted. How can I return the full path without the first and last single quotes?

```
body {
  background-image: 'url("//localhost:3000/dist/assets/myImage.jpg")';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the same function in all your styl files, Stylus functions will be more suitable. You can define a [function in stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/functions.html) as :

```
bodyCustomBg()
  body
    background-color white
```

and use the function as :

```
bodyCustomBg()
```

You can also pass parameters in the [functions](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/functions.html) too. It will be available in the files where you will import or require the .styl file containing the function.